# Client Certificate Validating and looking up customer

Tags: c#, ssl

I have set up a client server application and I have all the client.crt for each customer and they are linked to the customerId. during the server RemoteCertificateValidationCallback I want to validate the client cert (which already works) and then also look up the customer with this cert. do you use the Thumbprint only or do you need to do multiple checks?

Comment: If you have implemented the certificate verification correctly and only accept certificates that have Ben issued by your CA then you can use what ever property you want. You could even include the user id in the certificate and directly use it without db lookup. But all that requires that the cert verification works correctly and does not accept any other certificates.